# How to check constraints in Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

How do I create a CHECK constraint to check for a range of possible values in Sequel. a Ruby ORM.

All attempts seem to generate `CHECK (1 = 0)` as seen in the output logs.

Here's the table I'm trying to model using Sequel's DSL:

```
create table memberships(  
      id integer primary key autoincrement
    , group_id integer references groups(id) on delete cascade
    , user_id integer references users(id) on delete cascade
    , role char check (role in ('u','a','o')) default 'u'
    , unique(group_id, user_id, role)   
);
```

and here's the Sequel schema generation code:

```
db.create_table(:memberships){
    primary_key :id
    foreign_key :user_id, :users
    foreign_key :group_id, :groups  
    char :role, default: 'u'
    check{role=='u' or role=='a'} #<-----this line generates CHECK (1 = 0)
    unique [:user_id, :group_id, :role]
}
```

Comment: Yup, tried that one too. Same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Sequel, check constraints are handled just like a filter expression.  The recommended way to handle your case would be:

```
check(:role=>%w[a o u])
```

I agree that more documentation would probably be better, though there are examples in http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/schema_modification_rdoc.html

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth! Thanks for the taking the time to answer mate! And for all the hard work on the library!

Answer (score 3):

The documentation on how `check` and `add_constraint` are supposed to work is rather sparse but you could try bypassing all the magic entirely, write the constraint as you would in SQL, and return that from the block; something like this:

```
db.create_table(:memberships) {
    #...
    check { "role in ('a', 'o', 'u')" }
    #...
}
```

The language that is allowed in a CHECK constraint is quite rich and varied so I'd expect a simple string to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

This would be handled elegantly with an `enum`:

```rb
up do
  extension :pg_enum
  create_enum(:role_types, %w[a b c])
  create_table # ...
    role_types :role, null: false
#...

down do
  drop_table # :...
  drop_enum :role_types
end
```